# how to get form filled data in Jbpm 5.4

Tags: jbpm

I am creating an application using Jbpm 5.4 . Every user task has a task form and I competed them through Rest api. All work fine and data is going to tables. But I want to know how jbpm api get data which are filled by user in previous states? Ate those data associated with Content table? Can anyone explain how i get those filled data on my own?
I tried following.

```
try {
BlockingGetContentResponseHandlerresponseHandler=new BlockingGetContentResponseHandler();

client.getContent(contentId, responseHandler);

Content content = responseHandler.getContent();

byte[] byteContent = content.getContent();

ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteContent);

ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(byteArrayInputStream);

obj = inputStream.readObject();

} catch (Throwable t) {
t.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that the jbpm-console uses to get the task data: https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/5.4.x/jbpm-gwt/jbpm-gwt-form/src/main/java/org/jbpm/integration/console/forms/TaskFormDispatcher.java

Comment: Thanks Kris, I looked your answer and it really helped me to understand how it works. According to my understanding, task form content is saved as a byte array in Content table. Can't i use that array to take the form data directly?